# Simplex deformation retracts onto faces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am not able to construct explicitly a deformation retract of the 3-simplex [0, 1, 2, 3] onto a union of its faces [0 ,1, 2] and [1, 2, 3].  it seems easy, but everything I try fails because I can't figure out a way to deform points onto these faces in such a way that the points already on the face remain fixed.  Is it possible?  For example I could construct a map $\phi : \Delta^3 \times I \to I$ given by $(a, b, c, d, t) \mapsto (a-ta, b+ta, c+td, d-td)$ (deforming everything onto edge [1, 2]) but obviously this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $r(a,b,c,d)=(a-\lambda,\ b+\lambda,\ c+\lambda,\ d-\lambda)$ where $\lambda=\textrm{min}(a,d)$. This is a retraction $r$ of $\Delta^3$ to the faces. Since $\Delta^3$ is convex, you can just slide each point $x$ along the straight path to $r(x)$ during the time interval $I$.

Comment: ah..nice, that works!